# EncryptedIncrementalStore's compatibility with NSBatchDeleteRequest & NSBatchUpdateRequest

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am using EncryptedIncrementalStore in swift to use encryption with core data. I want to delete some records from one entity using NSBatchDeleteRequest, When I fetching the result, I am getting nil error in response.

Following method supports only NSFetchRequestType & NSSaveRequestType

```
- (id)executeRequest:(NSPersistentStoreRequest *)request
         withContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
               error:(NSError **)error
```

How can I use NSBatchDeleteRequest & NSBatchUpdateRequest?

Thanks.

Comment: `NSBatchDeleteRequest` and `NSBatchUpdateRequest` are subclasses of `NSPersistentStoreRequest`. What happens when you try to use them?

Comment: @TomHarrington EncryptedIncrementalStore supports only NSFetchRequest & NSSaveChangesRequest. When I am trying to use NSBatchDeleteRequest & NSBatchUpdateRequest, I am getting an error with nil description because this requests are not handled in EncryptedIncrementalStore.

Comment: @TomHarrington Hi, Can you help me in this?